# Unable to access EC2 instance public IPv4 DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, ipv4

I created an instance on AWS EC2, but I met a problem when reaching the AWS instance public IPv4 DNS via the link provided.

IPv4 DNS address:

[image: IPv4 DNS address]

Security rules:

[image: Security rules]

I have tried several ways like changing HTTPS to HTTP, and changing the firewall (I closed my OS firewall), but still can't reach it. I work from home using a VPN, will this cause the problem?

Chrome result:

[image: chrome result]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: See [Troubleshoot connecting to your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html).

Comment: Can you SSH into the EC2 instance? Did you install a web server on the instance?